# How to iterate through all div and get specific property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

what I'm trying to do is iterate over a collection of div, contained in a parent container. My structure is the following:

```
<div id='main'>
   <div data-id='2'>
  </div>
  <div data-id='3'>
  </div>
</div>
```

My goal is take the field `data-id` of each `div` and create an array collection. Previously I used the `select` where do I get each value of available option, like this:

```
var available_services = $('#selected-service').find('option', this).map(function ()
{
      return this.value;
}).get();
```

But now I'm using a div collection instead of the select. How I can iterate through all available `div`?

Comment: have you tried `$('#main > div').each(...)` or `.map` depending on what you need as an end result?

Comment: Good idea, I'll try it thanks!

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/wue1q1zt/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this will do it:

```
var available_services = [];
$('#main div').each(function(){
available_services.push($(this).data( "id" ));
})
```

Answer (score 4):

This should return all `data-id` values in a list:

```
var available_services = $('#main').find('div').map(function (item)
{
    return item.attr('data-id');
});
```

I didn't test this, but I think should do the job. (maybe you need to tweak a little bit)

Answer (score 2):

This is the easy way to go:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var myCollection = [];
     $('#main div').each(function(){
         var dataDiv = $(this).attr('data-id');
         myCollection.push(dataDiv)
     })

 });
```

Comment: This is not answer of the question. Please, fix your answer.

Comment: @alirezasafian, I was reading this 'My goal is take the field data-id of each div', and that's why I gave this answer.

Comment: 1-  `dataDiv ` variable is not accessible out of `.each` function. 2-  `dataDiv ` variable keep the last value of `data-id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
(function(){
  var main = $("#main");
  var divs = $(main).find("div");
  
  var arrId = divs.map(function(index, div){
    return $(div).attr("data-id");
  });
  
  console.log(arrId);
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='main'>
   <div data-id='2'>
  </div>
  <div data-id='3'>
  </div>
</div>
```